# Linked list find() method . How to

Tags: java

okey, I have a linked list (not collections) and I created a new method for find an object in my Linked list. So something like this:

```
 public Object find(Linked obj) {

        Linked newObj = firstLink;

        while(newObj != null) {

            if(newObj == obj) {
                return obj;
            }
            else {

                newObj = newObj.next;
            }
        }
```

By the way, I have **2 classes**: `Linked` and `Linkedlist`. In the first one, I **have a reference to the next node and display function.** The main action is in Linkedlist where I have all methods like insert, display and a `firstLink` reference (the last inserted node in my list) ( my find() method also is in this class). So in my main function I am doing this:

```
Linkedlist obj = new Linkedlist();
obj.insert("Auto");

Linkedlist obj2 = new Linkedlist();
obj2.insert("Moto");
```

And how can I call my method `find()` to check if my `Linkedlist` has (for example) `obj2` ?

Comment: use newObj.equals(obj) (after you override it in Linked class) and be aware that obj2 is a Linkedlist, not an object to look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think it this way:

You have Linked class (this is a linked list node, and each node should have the next pointer and the element inside the node). So this class should have constructor,setter,and getter methods.

On the other hand, Linkedlist class is your main class that manage the Linked object (that is managing the linked list node). In this class you should have reference to the root node (the very first node you insert). So in your program, you should only have one/more Linked object and Linkedlist as your main class.

```
Linked root = new Linked("Auto",null); //here Linked constructor takes 2 parameters, the element and the next pointer.
//Since you only inserted one element so far, the next element should be null.

//Insert another element
insertAtEnd("Moto");

public void insertAtEnd(String element){
    Linked curr = root;
    while(curr.next != null) curr = curr.next;
    curr.setNext(new Linked(element,null);
}

public Linked findElement(String element){
    Linked curr = root;
    while(curr!=null){
         if(curr.getElement().equals(element)) return curr;
         else curr = curr.next;
    }
    return null; //element not found
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you. It works! I take your code if statement. And it is an easy way to compare it because there is no point to compare 2 objects if there is only 1 var. So using your way, I do not need to override my equals() and hashCode(). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- To compare a single object in LinkedList to another one:

  Implement the method `equals()`for `Linked`. Within  this method check if the Strings contained in both objects (current object in the iteration and the object to find) are the same. To do so, you should use the `String.equals(String other)`method
- To compare two LinkedLists, write another `equals()` method. This time for `LinkedList`. In this method you should compare e.g. the number of elements in boths lists. If the lists contain the same number of elements, you can use the previously defined `Linked.equals()` to compare the lists item by item.

Comment: Yes  after 5 minutes I posted my post, I thought about equals(). thanks by the way